# How to use combobox to change the richTextBox font size

Tags: c#, combobox, textbox, richtextbox

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//change font size
{          
    if (toolStripComboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Comic Sans MS", 12);
    }

    if (toolStripComboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Comic Sans MS", 19);
    }
}
```

Here is my code, in this situation I have to click "19" twice to make it work, what's error of my code

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a look at:https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841337/7124761

Comment: Maybe you meant to change Font instead of SelectionFont.  Select some text before you change it to see the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void toolStripComboBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted += ComboBoxOnSelectionChangeCommitted;
        }


private void ComboBoxOnSelectionChangeCommitted(object o, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            switch (toolStripComboBox1.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Comic Sans MS", 12);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Comic Sans MS", 19);
                    break;
                default:
                    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Comic Sans MS", 9);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

You can also use if instead switch, but personaly i would prefer switch in this situation.